# Как позиционировать элементы в React?

Tags: reactjs, позиционирование

Всем привет! Делаю сайт на реакт и у меня есть компонент Enrollment [image: Компонент Enrollment]

Хочу сделать так чтобы картинка была справа текста.
Вот код:

```
<section className="enroll-section spad set-bg" src={img}>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-5">
              <div className="section-title text-white">
                <h3 style={{paddingLeft: "25mm"}}>ENROLLMENT</h3>
                <p style={{paddingLeft: "25mm"}}>Get started with us to explore the exciting</p>
                <img style={{height: "200px"}} src={image} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className="enroll-list text-white">
                <div className="enroll-list-item">
                  <span style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>1</span>
                  <h5 style={{paddingLeft: "25mm"}}>Contact</h5>        
                  <p style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sitdo amet, consectetur dont adipis elit. <br/> Vivamus interdum ultrices augue.</p>
                </div>
                <div className="enroll-list-item">
                  <span style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>2</span>
                  <h5 style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>Consulting</h5>
                  <p style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sitdo amet, consectetur dont adipis elit.<br/> Vivamus interdum ultrices augue.</p>
                </div>
                <div className="enroll-list-item">
                  <span style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>3</span>
                  <h5 style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>Register</h5>
                  <p style={{marginLeft: "26mm"}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sitdo amet, consectetur dont adipis elit.<br/> Vivamus interdum ultrices augue.</p>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 p-lg-0 p-4">
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Вот что должно получится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: react тут не причем просто отдели div-ами(а лучше отдельные компоненты) закинь в какой то div и этому div-у поставь display:flex

Comment: @Armen не совсем понял. Можно код

Answer (score 0):

[![Сделал все как вы сказали. ][1]][1]

```
<div style={{display:flex}}>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>photo</div>
</div>
```

Отделил все дивами и написал display: flex вот что получилось][1]][1]    <div style={{display:flex}}
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFEe8.png

Comment: @НизомидинНизомиддинов друг мой изучи flex хотя бы, будь добр и сделай все правильно